# Error: "unexpected keyword else, expected keyword end"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedded-ruby

I am learning rails and I get a syntax error `unexpected keyword else, expected keyword end` on the following code and I don t know why.

```
<% if @quo.pro_con.nil? do %>
  <div class="procon">
    <%= f.label :pro_con %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :pro_con %>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
<% else %> 
  <p>
    <strong>Pro Con:</strong>
    <%= @quo.pro_con %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= @quo.comment %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Why am I receiving the error, `unexpected keyword else, expected keyword end`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if` does not require `do` clause. The interpreter sees `do` and awaits `end` to match. Change your first line to:

```
<% if @quo.pro_con.nil? %>
```